# What is the criterion of stability of thick-walled spherical shell?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stability, solid-mechanics

Is there the formula (if someone already has discovered it) or what is the algorithm (if a particular formula was not deduced), to calculate the critical pressure of thick-walled spherical shell $−$ the pressure which provokes buckling?